# Select each instance of a pattern, inside a pattern, with regex?

Tags: regex, replace, html-parsing, sublimetext

I am trying to remove spaces from inside HTML IDs on headings, and replace them with a - character. So far, I have been doing a multi step process instead. I would like to condense this to one step using regex. I have been trying to make a regex pattern that will highlight instances of a character, inside a variable pattern, but I have not had much success.

The regex should replace 2 spaces here:

```
<h2 id="three word sentence">
```

The regex should replace 3 spaces here:

```
<h2 id="four words in sentence">
```

This is what I have so far, which finds the entire ID on each item. Then I turn on "find in selection" and replace spaces with `-`.

```
(?<=<h[234] id=").*(?=")
```

How can I find just the spaces in one step?

Comment: RegExp isn’t a great tool for manipulating HTML/XML-like markup, you really should consider using a proper HTML parser to complete this and perform a simple string replacement on each `id` value.

Comment: @esqew Thank you. What I'm doing now is creating chained find-and-replace automations in Sublime Text to add IDs based on what the headings are, then formatting the IDs appropriately. I haven't used an HTML parser before -- can you advise what I should look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?:\G(?!\A)|<h\d+\s+id=")[^"\s]*\K\s+(?=[^"]*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ENZLm/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|<h\d+\s+id=")` - either the end of the previous successful match or `<h`, one or more digits, one or more whitespaces and `id="` string
- `[^"\s]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` and whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=[^"]*")` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char immediately to the right of the current position.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! I have not used \G(?!\A) or \K before, those were my missing pieces! Thanks for teaching me something new. Also I didn't think you were allowed to use * in a lookahead?!

Comment: @RCS You can use `*` quantifier in the lookahead in any regex flavor.

Comment: nice, i have enough points now to upvote! :)